# Summing common columns of multi table parent-child relation in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL query

```
SELECT        dbo.a.Agency, SUM(COALESCE (dbo.b.total, 0)) + SUM(COALESCE (dbo.c.total, 0)) 
                     + SUM(COALESCE (dbo.d.total, 0)) AS Expr1,
dbo.b.date as date,
dbo.c.Date AS Expr2, 
dbo.d.Date AS Expr3
FROM            dbo.c RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.a ON dbo.d.Agency = dbo.a.Agency LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.c ON dbo.a.Agency = dbo.c.Agency LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.b ON dbo.a.Agency = dbo.b.Agency
GROUP BY dbo.a.Agency, dbo.b.Date, dbo.c.Date, dbo.d.Date
```

What I would like to achieve is to group on the 3 date fields at the same time. so a result would look like this

```
+------+-------+----+
|Agency|expr1  |Date|
+------+-------+----+
|abc   |500000 |18  |
+------+-------+----+
|def   |6000000|18  |
+------+-------+----+
|abc   |550000 |19  |
+------+-------+----+
|def   |750000 |19  |
+------+-------+----+
```

Date just contains int values as the example demonstrates. they are linked to another table which could be used if this is easier.

The current code just shows 1 line for each date value for each table. If I use a filter using `AND` or `OR` it shows incorrect results

Answer (score 0):

never mind. I solved it by using a cross apply and using a Date = 21 in the where clause